# Display first value unless checkbox is checked, then calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

So I spent many hours working on a dynamic Booking form. I manage to get the hide and show functions to work as I want and that the values change according to the chosen Radio button. For the next step I want to calculate the values. But I want to first display the Value of the Radio. Then when the user checks a checkbox, add the value of each checked checkbox to the value of the Radio. I managed to get the function of adding all checked boxes and add that to the radio value.

```
        var sum1;
    $('input[name=price]').change(function() {
        sum1 = $('input[name=price]:checked').val();
    });
    $('input[name=custompak]').change(function() {
        var sum2 = 0;
        $('input[name=custompak]:checked').each(function() {
        sum2 += parseInt($(this).prop('value'));
    });
      document.getElementById('finalprice').innerHTML = parseInt(sum1) + parseInt(sum2);
    });
```

This is the JSFiddle of the Complete form:
https://jsfiddle.net/mullern/2cr91vvq/2/

FYI, the rest of the JS code changes the value depending on the Customertype selection and it also hides the checkboxes of the products already included in the bundle.

My goal is to Display the price of the Packages shown in the radiogroup when one is selected. Then when one or more checkboxes are selected, that value gets added to the value of the radiogroup selection.

On a sidenote I was also not able to figure out how to display the Value when the page is loaded so the user sees the default selection value when they open the contact form.

I hope this isn't to confusing and thank you in advance for any help on my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [fiddle][1], Try clicking on radio button under packages. You are suppose to write code on click event. I also tried to minimize your code by calling method , check line 13 to 22.

```
 [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/2cr91vvq/3/
```

Comment: I suppose I could shorten my code by using more variables, but this didn't actually answer my question.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? Also try clicking on the radio button I have coded  to show alert. The code shows you how to get radio button click event. You can get the value by $(this).val(). Good luck.

Comment: I went over my code and tried out some stuff. I managed to display the value of the radio at the bottom of the form. But now I am stuck on adding the values together. I thought that using the base value of 0 for the checkbox sum would help that I can just add 0 or the checked value to the radio value. Check my Fiddle:


https://jsfiddle.net/mullern/2cr91vvq/5/


I'm trying to get the value of the radio and checkbox into one var each so I can add them together but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I hope this one will fix your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/2cr91vvq/6/

Comment: I am getting there. I managed to display both values in 2 different <p> to see if it works. But now I am stuck on how to add them together. I read that the way to do it is by using global variables. I'm not sure how to do that correctly. It always says undefined variable because the variables are in a function. How do I make them global so I can add them?

https://jsfiddle.net/mullern/2cr91vvq/7/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think your way is a more effective way of learning how to do it. I guess in the beginning I was a little too lazy to try but now I tried different methods and only asked when I ran out of ideas.